# "Takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" Принимает 1 аргумент, когда 2 были даны

Tags: python, python-3.x

Выдаёт неизвестную ошибку, как это исправить? (я новичок)

Ошибка:
*BuildPath() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given*

Мой Код:

```py
class Object:
    posX = 0;
    posY = 0;
    def __init__(self, posX, posY):
        self.posX = posX
        self.posY = posY
    class Bot(Object):
    def __init__(self, posX, posY):
        posY = Object.posY
        posX = Object.posX

    def BuildPath(targetPosition):
        x = targetPosition[0] - posX
        y = targetPosition[1] - posY
        print(targetPosition[1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае не стоит добавлять один класс в другой.(Вы же хотите использовать наследование).
И в методе buildPath пропущен ключевое слово self.

```
class Object:
    posX = 0;
    posY = 0;
    def __init__(self, posX, posY):
        self.posX = posX
        self.posY = posY
class Bot(Object):
    def __init__(self, posX, posY):
            self.posY = Object.posY
            self.posX = Object.posX

    def BuildPath(self,targetPosition):
            x = targetPosition[0] - self.posX
            y = targetPosition[1] - self.posY
            print(targetPosition[1])
obj=Object(1,2)
Bot=Bot(1,2)
Bot.BuildPath([4,5])
```

Comment: @MaxU Да... чего то я не исправил до конца . Вот теперь правильно ;)

Comment: Стоило бы ещё дать небольшое пояснение, чтобы автору вопроса была понятна причина ошибки